# Reading duration of an mp4 file using jquery

Tags: jquery, duration, modalpopup

My main requirement is to display the video in a modal popup for that i'm using the below functionality..

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="wmBox" href="#" data-popup="vendor_reg.mp4">
        <img src='images/vendor_reg.png' />
    </a>
    <a class="wmBox" href="#" data-popup="workflow.mp4">
        <img src='images/workflow.png' />
    </a>
</div>
```

Below is the jquery functionality i'm writing to read the duration

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href]').each(function(){
            var data= $(this).attr('data-popup').duration;
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

But i'm getting undefined.

**Note:** If anyone has a solution about how to show `HTML5` video's in a modal popup kindly let me know.

Comment: by `$(this).attr('data-popup')` you are just getting the string. Its not a `video` object. So first load that video and then only you will get its other properties.

Comment: If you want to get the duration of a video through client side means you must load them first..